# Is 'thought it to be' grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, phrases, infinitives

Does

> If man continues to scathe all of Earth and its seas, then this isn’t
>   the world I thought it to be

make sense? Or should I just replace the 'to' with 'would'?

Comment: Yes, makes sense and is grammatical. Its literary style or suitability otherwise may be a different matter, though. Replacing with *would* gives a different meaning as you know -- so choice depends on what you meant to say. Instead you could consider *was* in place of *to be*.

Comment: *Maybe the disagreement between the two men had not been as resolved as Chelsea had thought it to be.* (Victoria Morris); *Eventually Orwell came to understand that this was not the practical policy he had at first thought it to be.* (Lionel Trilling);

Comment: Kris please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I completely agree with Kris.

It is grammatical and comprehensible.

I thought it to be translates into *I thought it is/was.*

*Would* has an element of prediction or hope which is not your intention I presume.

To is more assertive and definitely well suited.